# Loading File in Flex without AIR?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, file

i am using flexbuilder 3 
now i need to load xml file from disk using flex without AIR
i imported flash.filesystem.File but error occured.
but AIR project,flash.filesystem.File was successfully imported.
Cant i use flash.filesystem.File from flex without using AIR???

Answer (score 2):

You can only use `flash.filesystem.File` in AIR.  But you can still load XML files using either HTTPService or URLLoader.  Check out this answer which has [sample code for loading XML into Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195950/initializing-a-collection-from-mxml/2196777#2196777).

If you get a Security Sandbox Error when trying to load, set the Flex Compiler argument `use-network=false`, which will allow you to load local files into the swf.